# Download universal package inside docker and create new image out of it

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

So my requirement is to use

- CentOs 8 as a base image
- Connect to Azure DevOps universal package
- Install custom package from Azure DevOps universal package and
- Finally create a new image custom image with CentOs + downloaded universal package

Can anyone guide me on how should I go about it ?

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

[Containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops#endpoints) can be hosted on registries other than Docker Hub. To host an image on Azure Container Registry or another private container registry, add a [service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to the private registry. Then we could use the container in the pipeline, such as:

```
container:
  image: xxx/xxx:tag
  endpoint: xxx
```

> Connect to Azure DevOps universal package and Install custom package from Azure DevOps universal package

We could connect and download the universal package via the task [Universal package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/universal-packages?view=azure-devops)(Command is download)

> create a new image custom image with CentOs + downloaded universal package

We could refer to [Build an image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/build-image?view=azure-devops) and [Push an image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/push-image?view=azure-devops) to build and publish new image.